# Prove for all sets A, B, and C, if A-B ⊆ C then A-C ⊆ B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I did a venn diagram and this statement is TRUE. Im just not too sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You want to show that $A\setminus C\subseteq B$, so start with an arbitrary $x\in A\setminus C$; what do you know about it? By definition $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Suppose that $x\notin B$; then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $x\in A\setminus B$; can you see how to finish it from here?

Comment: I definitely understood that part but im not too sure how I can end up with A-C ⊆ B

Comment: @Jam: Remember the hypothesis that $A\setminus B\subseteq C$: if $x\in A\setminus B$, then $x\in C$. But you started with an $x\in A\setminus C$; is that possible?

Comment: So if i was writing a proof i would say "because x∈A∖B, x∈C in A∖B⊆C. Therefore A∖C⊆B is correct" ?

Comment: But i know i would start off with " Assume ABC are sets. Assume A-B⊆C"

Comment: @Jam: Yes, that’s how you’d start; I took that bit for granted. Then you’d let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A\setminus C$ and try to show that $x\in B$. My suggestion was that you prove this by contradiction: if $x\notin B$, then (*something happens*), which is a contradiction, so $x\in B$. I’m pretty sure from your previous comment that you didn’t actually understand the argument that I was suggesting; at any rate, the answer to that question is *no*, because what you wrote isn’t enough to justify the conclusion that $A\setminus C\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this: calculate for which sets both statements are true, using the definitions, and simplify using logic.

First let's tackle $\;A - B \subseteq C\;$:
\begin{align}
& A - B \subseteq C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A - B \Rightarrow x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;-\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \not\in B \Rightarrow x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify: expand $\;p \Rightarrow q\;$ into $\;\lnot p \lor q\;$; DeMorgan"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in A \lor x \in B \lor x \in C \rangle \\
\end{align}
Now do the same for $\;A - C \subseteq B\;$, and draw your own conclusions.